# Magento - Product review page layout changes not reflecting

Tags: product, layout, review, magento1.9.3

Totaly new to Magento and working with version 1.9.3.8.

I am trying to change the layout of product review page from 2columns to 1column by editing the review.xml file present in the following path `default/layout/review.xml`.

This is what my code looks like.

```
<review_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Review View</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="review/view" name="review_view"/>
    </reference>
</review_product_view>
```

The changes are not reflecting. Am I missing something somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are changing file in your theme and clear cache after changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change layout in review_product_list handler, not in "review_product_view". Try this then flush your cache , hope it will work

```
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate"> 
              <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
         </action>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

Comment: I  am changing review_product_list handler but not working

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with this handle: review_product_list

The issue is that that handle is not loading when the reviews page is selected.

If you go ahead and add this line to your form:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

You will see that the handle review_product_list is not in that array, on the contrary you will see this handle: catalog_product_view

I bet you that if you change this:

```
<review_product_list>
  <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate"> 
          <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
     </action>
  </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

For this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate"> 
          <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
     </action>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

It will work, obviously not where you want that to be added but the reason is the loading of that particular handle.

Any ideas about this issue?